# Telethon events.NewMessage limits for channels to monitor

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I made a Telegram bot using the Telethon library. The bot's task is to check all new messages in the channels to which I am subscribed and forward these messages to another channel (message aggregator).

I created a list that contains all links to channels (50 in total). Initially, I tested the list for 5 channels and everything worked fine. But when I try to use full list (50 channels) nothing works. The error does not appear either. It just does nothing.

Please tell me what is the limit on the number of channels? How can I fix this?

```
chats = ['@chat1', '@chat2', '@chat3']
```

```
client = TelegramClient('927', api_id, api_hash, device_model="realme 10", system_version="Android 12")
```

```
client.start(phone = PHONE)
print("start client")
```

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chats))
async def message_handler(event):
    if event.message:
        print(event.message)
        await client.forward_messages('@chatDest', event.message)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

````
client.run_until_disconnected()```
````